# Como fazer trigger('change') em um input select?

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de simular um evento de change no meu input, mas não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.

Assim que a página carrega eu seleciono um valor diferente no meu input dessa forma:

```
$("#selExercicio option:contains('" + ano + "')").prop("selected", true);
```

Está funcionando.

Em seguida eu tento fazer o trigger:

```
$("#selExercicio").trigger("change");
```

O meu evento de mudança de input é este:

```
$("#selExercicio").change(function () {
    debugger;
    alert('Mudou');
});
```

E não está chamando o alert no carregamento da página, apenas quando eu mudo o valor do input clicando com o mouse.

Alguém tem idéia do por quê não estar funcionando?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Skzp5/1/)

Comment: Tem como fazer um [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproduzindo o problema?

Comment: O código onde você faz o `trigger` é executado antes ou depois do código onde você atribui o *handler*?

Comment: O trigger é executado que eu modifico o valor selecionado. O que você chama de handler? Vou tentar fazer o fiddle.

Comment: Postei o Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Skzp5/1/

Comment: @JoaoPaulo *event handler* - a função anônima que você passou como parâmetro pra `$(...).change`. Vejo que, de fato, o problema estava na ordem invertida.

Comment: Você pode também utilizar apenas `$("#selExercicio").change()`. Chamar a função `change` sem passar parâmetro dispara o evento de mudança. Isso vale também para todos os demais métodos do jQuery que lidam com eventos ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro era que:

```
$("#selExercicio").trigger("change");
```

estava sendo chamado antes de:

```
$("#selExercicio").change(function () {
    debugger;
    alert('Mudou');
});
```

Inverti e funcionou.